How to estimate the pH range of a 100ml solution containing 20g citric acid and 5g sodium bicarbonate?
I want to make a fabric softening solution that has sodium citrate and citric acid in it for its stronger water softening properties. Raising the pH is meant to make it less aggressive on the fabric, hence the addition of baking soda to react and form sodium citrate. I want to estimate the range of the pH for such a solution.

For such high concentrations is very difficult to calculate pH, as there are many factors hard to theoretize and predict. It is better to be measured by pH meter if applicable. // For more diluted solutions see sigmaaldrich.com - buffer-reference-center#citric2, with easy recalculation for baking soda.

@Poutnik It doesnt have to be super accurate, pH can range from 2.8-3.8. I just want to avoid too much acidity for the fabric sake.

Is it the final concentration or will it be diluted ? As for the latter, it should be evaluated for the final concentration.

I have citric acid crystal so I can adjust. And correct for the latter, it will be diluted in the washing machine so even higher pH.

And why not just add enough citrix acid to water to address with excess any reasonable water hardness value? Or, is there a requirement for mild acidity?

Because I want to leverage sodium citrate's water softening abilities as well, by adding baking soda to the mix. So instead of making a specific concentration of citric acid to get the desired pH, I want to include sodium citrate as well. Also like you said, mild acidity is preferable.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If you essentially want a buffer, then just add as much moles of bicarbonate as acid.

As CO2 bubbles out, the pH will change.

@DrMoishePippik I am adding baking soda to it to change the pH baking soda 5g to 20g citric acid. I still want to keep it acidic. I guess Ill use that method until I buy a pH meter.

Is citric acid concentration is $w/v$ or $w/w$? If it is latter, need density as well.
